# uwsgi: missed --log-filter option

Tags: logging, filter, uwsgi

I am using uWSGI and want to filter logs (I don't need to log requests on several endpoints). I've found that uWSGI has an special [option](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#log-filter) called *log-filter* for doing that.

But my uwsgi binary don't recognize this option:

```
$ uwsgi --help | grep log-
--log-format                            set advanced format for request logging
--log-format-strftime                   apply strftime to logformat output
--log-syslog                            log to syslog
--log-socket                            send logs to the specified socket
--log-encoder                           add an item in the log encoder chain
--log-req-encoder                       add an item in the log req encoder chain
--backlog-alarm                         raise the specified alarm when the socket backlog queue is full
--log-master                            delegate logging to master process
--log-master-bufsize                    set the buffer size for the master logger. bigger log messages will be truncated
--log-master-stream                     create the master logpipe as SOCK_STREAM
--log-master-req-stream                 create the master requests logpipe as SOCK_STREAM
--log-reopen                            reopen log after reload
--log-truncate                          truncate log on startup
--log-maxsize                           set maximum logfile size
--log-backupname                        set logfile name after rotation
--log-date                              prefix logs with date or a strftime string
--log-prefix                            prefix logs with a string
--log-zero                              log responses without body
--log-slow                              log requests slower than the specified number of milliseconds
--log-4xx                               log requests with a 4xx response
--log-5xx                               log requests with a 5xx response
--log-big                               log requestes bigger than the specified size
--log-sendfile                          log sendfile requests
--log-ioerror                           log requests with io errors
--log-micros                            report response time in microseconds instead of milliseconds
--log-x-forwarded-for                   use the ip from X-Forwarded-For header instead of REMOTE_ADDR
--rsyslog-packet-size                   set maximum packet size for syslog messages (default 1024) WARNING! using packets > 1024 breaks RFC 3164 (#4.1)
--rsyslog-split-messages                split big messages into multiple chunks if they are bigger than allowed packet size (default is false)
--cheaper-busyness-backlog-alert        spawn emergency worker(s) if any time listen queue is higher than this value (default 33)
--cheaper-busyness-backlog-multiplier   set cheaper multiplier used for emergency workers (default 3)
--cheaper-busyness-backlog-step         number of emergency workers to spawn at a time (default 1)
--cheaper-busyness-backlog-nonzero      spawn emergency worker(s) if backlog is > 0 for more then N seconds (default 60)
```

I have latest version of uWSGI:

```
$ uwsgi --version
2.0.19.1
```

What do i miss?

Answer (score 0):

for the option --log-filter uwsgi should be compiled with pcre support